# Work with Telegram API : API_ID_INVALID

Tags: android, netbeans, telegram

I am developing an android application that use from telegram api.

I use from "telegram-sample" in "https://github.com/telegram-s/telegram-api".

Also, I get my api_id and api_hash from telegram website.

When I am authentication, I receive an error: "RpcException: API_ID_INVALID"

This error occurs on

```
sentCode = api.doRpcCallNonAuth(new TLRequestAuthSendCode(phone, 0, 5, "1c5c96d5edd401b1ed40db3fb5633e2d", "en"));
```

(I test it with my api_id and api_hash)

What is the Problem?

Can any one help me?

Comment: https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/46 Maybe this issue will help you